# I can't find 'fdinfo' in the /proc file system

Tags: linux

I've read about the great uses of `/proc/<pid>/fd` and specifically **fdinfo** in this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110114195606/http://blog.ksplice.com/2011/01/solving-problems-with-proc/).
But I can't find it on my Linux system: Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4, kernel 2.6.9.
Where can I find the missing **fdinfo** ?

Comment: Mathew, thanks for pointing out that this is clearly stated in the article (I failed to notice it). But is there any way to add the functionality?

Comment: if there is, it will probably require recompiling your kernel, or at least adding a module.  Neither is likely to be easy, since RHEL 4 came out in 2005, while it looks like this feature was added in [March 2007](http://lwn.net/Articles/227746/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article clearly says, "All of these tricks should work on a recent Linux kernel, though some will fail on older systems like RHEL version 4."  As you can see, `fdinfo` is not available on your system.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/<pid>/fd` is present in Linux since 2.6.22 kernel version. You may want to upgrade your kernel.

Comment: That's going to be a challenging upgrade, given that RHEL 4 uses 2.6.9.

Comment: Tough luck. Old distros like RHEL do mean pain.